# Remote Desktop PowerShell Scripting

Tags: .net, powershell, remote-desktop

I cannot access the `UserAssignment` container using .net.  I am able to get to the application container but no further.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  The code I am using is:

```
Private Function runScript2(userName As String, applicationName As String) As String
    Dim rs As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace
    rs.Open()

    Dim ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create
    ps.Runspace = rs
    Dim sb2 As New StringBuilder
    sb2.AppendLine("Import-Module -Name C:\RemoteDesktopServices\RemoteDesktopServices.psd1")
    sb2.AppendLine("Get-ChildItem -Path RDS:\") 'this works
    sb2.AppendLine("Get-ChildItem -Path RDS:\RemoteApp\RemoteAppPrograms\WordPad\")  'this works
    sb2.AppendLine("Get-ChildItem -Path RDS:\RemoteApp\RemoteAppPrograms\WordPad\UserAssignment") 'this does not work, no error
    sb2.AppendLine("Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyScripts")
    ps.AddScript(sb2.ToString)

    Dim output As Collection(Of PSObject) = ps.Invoke
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each obj As PSObject In output
        If TypeOf (obj.BaseObject) Is DirectoryInfo Then
            Dim fle As DirectoryInfo = CType(obj.BaseObject, DirectoryInfo)
            sb.AppendLine(fle.FullName)
        ElseIf TypeOf (obj.BaseObject) Is FileInfo Then
            Dim fle As FileInfo = CType(obj.BaseObject, FileInfo)
            sb.AppendLine(fle.FullName)
        Else
            sb.AppendLine(obj.BaseObject.ToString)
        End If
    Next
    Return sb.ToString

End Function
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Yes the server is running 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fail, you simply has no any `UserAssignment`s yet, so it return you nothing. As soon as you will add some user - it will return it. You can check it by adding user manually through `Computer Management` console

Comment: There are three users assigned.  The commands work if manually typed into PowerShell.

Comment: @JimEggert Are you sure there are no other WordPad applications? Otherwise it could pick the wrong one

Comment: I tried a couple of other apps as well.  I can see the contents of the <app> container, but not the <app>\UserAssignment container.  But the commands work fine if typed directly into PowerShell.  I am not sure if there are extra permissions required for the UserAssignment container.

Comment: @JimEggert Who is running your code? Is it the same user that you've tried Powershell  directly with, or some service user? Do you have UAC on?